# Disable App Insights Performance Counter collection with App Service agent

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the App Service bundled App Insights agent with a .Net 4.7 app, and am *not* using the SDK. The only options I have for configuring the agent is with app settings, as described in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net#enable-agent-based-monitoring

Because I'm not using the SDK, I don't have an `applicationInsights.config` file, or `appsettings.json` file to put configuration info in, nor can I execute code to configure the collectors or initializers.

Can anyone help me figure out how to disable collection of performance counters in this case?

Docs say you can use specially crafted app settings like `MicrosoftAppInsights_AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor_InitialSamplingPercentage`, but I can't figure out what app setting I'd use to disable the perf counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with the product team and this is currently not possible with the agent-based monitoring in App Services. If you want to disable this module you will need to use the SDK so you can remove perf counters module.

Comment: Thanks @SamaraSoucy-MSFT. Not the answer I was hoping for, but appreciate the confirmation!